# split app.xaml styles into files

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, styles

I have on my app.xaml file many styles for my application . I want to split each style into a file, or doing another thing for  readability  . Now, it is impossible to go through the file, is to long.  I need an advice  for this. Is it  ok to split the app file into multiple files ?

Comment: You can use merged resourcedictionaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

put this in your app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="YourStylesFile.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```